# in SharePoint Calendar, How to add alternative text for next and previous button in other language?

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, accessibility, sharepoint-2013, alt

SharePoint Calendar in multilingual page. The next and previous navigation links of calendar does not add alternative text to image in other language (for example in Arabic) which is an issue and does not compliance with accessibility guidelines.

**In English it shows like**

```
<a id="WPQ2_nav_next_a" href="javascript:MoveToDate('2\u002f16\u002f2020','WPQ2');" title="Next Month"><img id="WPQ2_nav_next_img" src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/calnext.png" width="19" height="19" alt="Next button"></a>
```

**In Arabic it shows**

```
<a id="WPQ2_nav_next_a" href="javascript:MoveToDate('16\u002f02\u002f2020','WPQ2');" title="الشهر القادم"><img id="WPQ2_nav_next_img" src="/_layouts/15/1025/images/calnext.png" width="19" height="19"></a>
```

please advise.

Comment: I was unaware sharepoint was something you could do anything with, is there some library / plugin you are using where you have access to the source code / can host the calendar on your own site in a way where you can hook into with javascript? If not then the advice is use a different calendar as there is nothing you can do.

Comment: adding javascript does not work as most of the compliance tool check the html directly and does not run scripts. for reader it would be fine but does not pass through accessibility checkers/tools.

Comment: Do you just want the next and previous navigation links to show other languages or change the language to the whole environment ?

Comment: I just want to add alternative text to image tag for Arabic language. As shown above in English it generates image with alt tag but in Arabic it does not add alt tag.

Comment: Do you have control of the source code? That is the main point here, you need to be able to add the `alt` tags and as this is sharepoint I would guess you have no control. Also every accessibility checker worth using today checks the source code in the browser (Axe, Wave, Tenon) **after page load and JS execution** not the direct source from the server hence why I asked if you are able to run JavaScript on the page.

Comment: Graham, we are using sort-site to check accessibility but it does not execute jQuery before testing so still getting issue in the pages.. Below is the accessibility test page in which you can try any SharePoint calendar page to verify.
https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/accessibility-checks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above solution is fine, but after investigation more, found that there is a bug in the SharePoint calendar Previous button. It add ')' within the image tag which generate the issue.
To resolve that applied below,

```
jQuery("[id$='nav_prev_img']").removeAttr(')');
jQuery("[id$='nav_next_img']").attr('alt', 'Next button');
jQuery("[id$='nav_prev_img']").attr('alt', 'Previous button');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Test code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(change,"sp.ui.socialribbon.js")
function change(){
$("#WPQ2_nav_next_a").attr("title","الشهر القادم")

}
</script>
```

Test result:

[image]